# MvvmCross Android: Linking kills SwitchCompat.Checked propety

Tags: mvvmcross

I have layout with SwitchCompat binding to ViewModel

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:MvxBind="Checked FlashlightEnabled;
                         Click FlashlightCheckedCommand"/>
```

I also add in `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file some `Include` methods

```
public void Include(Switch s)
        {
            s.CheckedChange += (sender, args)
                => s.Checked = !s.Checked;
            s.Checked = true;
        }

        public void Include(SwitchCompat sc)
        {
            sc.CheckedChange += (sender, args)
                => sc.Checked = !sc.Checked;
            sc.Checked = true;
        }
```

But when I set the **Sdk and User Assemblies** linking, my Checked binding is removed.

**Output Message:**

2018-10-16 12:31:17 [WARN]  (MvxBind) Failed to create target binding for binding Checked for FlashlightEnabled10-16 12:31:17.143 I/mono-stdout( 5716):   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]

[image]

Comment: Can you verify that `SwitchCompat ` which is referenced in `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` is from the package of version `v7`?

Comment: Yes, I checked and added a picture to the question

Comment: Have you tried all the first-aid tricks like deleting bin/obj/vs folders, deleting packages folder and restoring them?

Comment: Yes it did not help

Comment: @NikitaGoncharuk, could you enable all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in [Exception Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017). This may help give you an idea as to what the exception is. From your extract `System.Activator.CreateInstance` it seems like it is a type instance creation that is failing.

Comment: For me adding the below code to linker.config fixed it:      <assembly fullname="MvvmCross">
    <type fullname="MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.Target.MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding"/>
  </assembly>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added `[Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` to your `LinkerPleaseInclude` class. If not the class will be ignored.

[Here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/ContentFiles/Android/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs) you have the latest `LinkerPleaseInclude` please be sure you have the same:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace $YourNameSpace$
{
    // This class is never actually executed, but when Xamarin linking is enabled it does how to ensure types and properties
    // are preserved in the deployed app
    [Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class LinkerPleaseInclude
    {
        public void Include(Button button)
        {
            button.Click += (s, e) => button.Text = button.Text + "";
        }

        public void Include(CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            checkBox.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(Switch @switch)
        {
            @switch.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => @switch.Checked = !@switch.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(View view)
        {
            view.Click += (s, e) => view.ContentDescription = view.ContentDescription + "";
        }

        public void Include(TextView text)
        {
            text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
        }

        public void Include(CheckedTextView text)
        {
            text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
        }

        public void Include(CompoundButton cb)
        {
            cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
        }

        public void Include(SeekBar sb)
        {
            sb.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => sb.Progress = sb.Progress + 1;
        }

        public void Include(RadioGroup radioGroup)
        {
            radioGroup.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => radioGroup.Check(args.CheckedId);
        }

        public void Include(RadioButton radioButton)
        {
            radioButton.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => radioButton.Checked = args.IsChecked;
        }

        public void Include(RatingBar ratingBar)
        {
            ratingBar.RatingBarChange += (sender, args) => ratingBar.Rating = 0 + ratingBar.Rating;
        }

        public void Include(Activity act)
        {
            act.Title = act.Title + "";
        }

        public void Include(INotifyCollectionChanged changed)
        {
            changed.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => { var test = $"{e.Action}{e.NewItems}{e.NewStartingIndex}{e.OldItems}{e.OldStartingIndex}"; };
        }

        public void Include(ICommand command)
        {
            command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) => { if (command.CanExecute(null)) command.Execute(null); };
        }

        public void Include(MvvmCross.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector injector)
        {
            injector = new MvvmCross.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector();
        }

        public void Include(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged changed)
        {
            changed.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var test = e.PropertyName;
            };
        }

        public void Include(MvxTaskBasedBindingContext context)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            var context2 = new MvxTaskBasedBindingContext();
            context2.Dispose();
        }

        public void Include(MvxNavigationService service, IMvxViewModelLoader loader)
        {
            service = new MvxNavigationService(null, loader);
        }

        public void Include(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            Console.Write("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            color = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        }
    }
}
```